# API to get posts from a Drupal blog?

Tags: drupal

I'm giving a shot to rebuilding the newsletter-maker for my wife's company. The prime issue is setting it up to always/automatically, say, link to the 3 most recent posts on their blog.

I can imagine how to start doing with with Rails and Javascript (my areas of "expertise" as a relatively amateur coder), except for the part where I have absolutely no idea where I would get this stream of posts.

The site (and thus the blog) is on Drupal. I know so zero about Drupal that I'm not 100% sure what "on Drupal" actually means. But I googled Drupal API and it's too vast for me to know where to start, and searching "blog" on the API site doesn't return anything helpful.

PS. I do know how to work with APIs. Once I find one!
PPS. Is this just a matter of working with RSS feeds? (Which I also don't know how to do but I imagine it's easy to find an answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an RSS feed with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

In short, you would have to take the following steps:

- create a view of the blog posts. Use filter criteria to select only published posts, and sort criteria to sort blogposts from most recent to older.
- add a display 'Feed'
- Under 'Feed settings' specify a path.

That's it. For more detailed tutorial, see e.g [this link](https://www.webomelette.com/create-rss-feed-based-any-content-type-drupal-7) (disclaimer: I'm not the author of the referred blogpost).

Finally, extract the latest three RSS items with your newsletter-maker.